# Can't reconnect to my RDP session

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

I use a VM through RDP.  When I'm done for the day, I just disconnect the session and reconnect in the morning.  That allows me to pick up what I was doing and not close all the applications.  As I'm the only user, this generally works well.

Today, I can't reconnect to my session from yesterday.  When I RDP, I get a new session.  When I run `query user`, I can see my other session:

```
 USERNAME   SESSIONNAME   ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 me         rdp-tcp#82     1  Active      15:00  4/22/2010 9:00 AM
>me         rdp-tcp#91     2  Active          .  4/30/2010 9:00 AM
```

If I try to use Terminal Services Manager to remote control the other session, I get this error:

```
Session (ID 1) remote control failed
(Error 7044 - The request to control another session remotely was denied. )
```

Is there any way to reconnect to this session, or do I need to just kill it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK just need to kill it, it's hung.